# Spring security configuration in `application.yml`, client or resource server?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I am getting confused by the spring security configuration. For example, I am developing a Spring-boot application. In project `resources/application.yml`, I can configure it as below to communicate with Keycloak(or any other OAuth2 server):

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          spring-app:
            client-id: spring-app
            client-secret: VWsQaq02oUYaWNzb51dKzACrF5QLgTm8
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope: openid, profile, roles
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/spring-app
        provider:
          spring-app:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8383/realms/foo
```

If I shrink above configuration to highlight the key things for my question later:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:

      client:
        registration:
          spring-app:
            ...
            ...
        provider:
          spring-app:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8383/realms/foo
```

I am basically configured my project as an OAuth2 **client**, and I also tell who is the OAuth2 server provider (Keycloak in my case, but it can be any other OAuth2 server).

**But If I change** the configuration completely to the following one in the same spring-boot project:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
     
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: ${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8383/realms/foo
```

As you can see, above configuration is a `resourceserver`(Resource Server) configuration, which treats my spring-boot application as a **resource server** instead of **client** in the context of OAuth2. The endpoints exposed by my spring-boot controllers are also protected by keycloak with this configuration (which I've tested), **as long as the** `issuer-uri` is pointing to keycloak uri.

I get very confused on when should I do **client** configuration and when should I do **resource server** configuration for my spring-boot project when using Spring Security?

I see both make sense, because my spring application is indeed an **OAuth2 client** being registered in Keycloak, and also my spring application is indeed a **resource server** which has endpoints exposed that should be protected by OAuth2 flow(s).

Could someone please clarify this for me, when to use which? Thanks in advance!

---

Dependencies in my project to verify things:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.2.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:3.2.3'

    // oauth2 client
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client:3.2.3'

    // oauth2 resource server
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server:3.2.3'
    ...
```

Comment: You use them as you specified. A resource server has resources (an API) that needs to be protected. While an oauth2 client is a server that acts as a client against your issuer (keycloak). Most commonly you have seperated micro services that have apis to access resources. And then you have a BFF (backend for frontend) that will initialize the login procedure and be the redirect point that later returns tokens as cookies (open id connect standard with AT, IT and RT tokens). And then some sort of proxy to exchange the cookie tokens to a JWT that is used between the microservice in the privat net

Comment: JWTs should never be handed to browsers and there are several sites that will explain why.

Comment: @Toerktumlare thanks for the comment. I understand what you explained. For my question, do you mean when using spring security, I should always configure my project both as a "client" (for OAuth2 server e.g. Keycloak) and as a "resource server" for protected APIs? Presuming my project is a backend service. My key point to ask is whether it is the convention to configure my project both as a client and a resource server like what I did in my context.

Comment: as i pointed out in my comment above `Most commonly you have seperated micro services that have apis to access resources. And then you have a BFF (backend for frontend)` The oauth2 specification does not explicit tell you how to do this its all about what you are building, a monolith or microservice architecture.

Comment: In plain words, OAuth2 Client should be used when you want to integrate OpenID/authorization flow. There is a server (in your case, keycloak) which provides  Authorization (and authentication in most of the cases) and you want to integrate the same. This is standard mechanism to enable federated logins such Google, facebook, github logins etc. Resource server flow is mainly to validate the token issued by an authorization server. JWT token primarily works with private-public certificate. A token issued by authorization server can be validated by any service using the public key issued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OAuth2 resource server processes requests from an OAuth2 client. So you use:

- OAuth2 client dependencies and conf when you need to get tokens from the authorization server to authorize requests to a resource server
- OAuth2 resource server dependencies and conf when you expose an API queried by OAuth2 client capable of authorizing requests with tokens

Note that:

- in clients using authorization_code flow (`oauth2Login` in Spring conf), the security is based on sessions, which requires protection against CSRF. In other words, when you send a request to a Spring app with `oauth2Login`, the request authorization is made with a session cookie, not a `Bearer` token. Also, it is generally expected that such an app responds with `302 redirect to login` to unauthorized requests to prtocted resources.
- in resource servers, sessions can (should?) be disabled along with CSRF protection because authorization is based on `Bearer` access tokens. It is generally expected that such an app responds with `401 unauthorized` to unauthorized requests to prtocted resources.

An application can be configured as both a client with `oauth2Login` and as an `oauth2ResourceServer`, but because of the very different security conf between the two, in such a case, I configure a separate `Security(Web)Filterchain` bean for each. For instance, my BFFs always are configured that way because it is a client by nature but also exposes REST endpoints like Actuator ones.

When resource servers call each others using client-credentials, client dependencies and conf are required to fetch the new tokens used in this inter service calls. But no need for a separate security filter-chain.

In the case where a service configured as a resource server calls another resource server on behalf of the resource owner who originated the request, it can forward the access token it received. In this case, the caller is a client for the other service, but doesn't need client deps and conf: the token is taken from the security context, not from the authorization server.

If you like to, you might find some more OAuth2 background and configuration tutorials from [this Github repo of mine](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#securing-spring-applications-with-oauth2)

Comment: Thanks @ch4mp! I like your answer!  But one thing in your answer is not clear to me, when you say `An application can be configured as both a client with oauth2Login and as an oauth2ResourceServer...`, however, in my project I am not using `oauth2Login` neither am I using `oauth2ResourceServer`.  I only configured in `application.yml` with the `client` section and `resourceserver` section, it also works well for both context. I suppose those two APIs you mentioned are not necessary in our discussion, right? Or do I misunderstand something still?

Comment: You are using Spring Boot and Spring Boot job is to provide with some auto-configuration based on properties and classpath. When you provide with an `authorization_code` client registration in properties, you're asking Spring Boot to setup a `Security(Web)FilterChain` with `oauth2Login` for you (unless you provide with a  `Security(Web)FilterChain` yourself, in which case Boot backs off). It is the same with `oauth2ResourceServer` and `resourceserver` properties.

Comment: thank you so much! You answer shows how deeply you understand Spring Security framework. May I ask do you have also other channel which I could follow your technical posts especially for spring security? Are you a youtuber?

Comment: I also noticed in your repo here https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/tutorials/servlet-client/src/main/resources/application.yml , you have specified `keycloak` under `provider`, but when I tried in my project, the `keycloak` has to be also under `client.registration` otherwise I get exception message `Provider ID must be specified for client registration`,  but you don't have it under client `registration`, how do you make it work with that `keycloak` provider?

Comment: the `keycloak-confidential-user` registration is set with `provider: keycloak` (the keys under `registration` are `registration-id`, so in this case, the registration ID to get access tokens from `keycloak` using authorization-code is `keycloak-confidential-user`). You can have several registrations referencing the same provider (for instance if you want to use different `authorization-grant-type`, `scope` or `client-id` for different calls ro resource server(s)).